# Enviar correo a un grupo de dominio

Tags: email, powershell, dominio, activedirectory

Mi Script generalmente recorre los usuarios para ver cuales no están deshabilitados y ver los días que le quedan para que expire la contraseña. Una vez recorre los usuarios recoge el mail y los días para expirar la contraseña y manda un correo.

Quiero mandar un correo a un grupo de dominio pero no me funciona excepto si pongo el SearchBase a una OU o a un usuario específico que entonces manda el correo perfectamente.

Pongo el código tratando de mandar a un grupo

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = get-aduser -filter {EmailAddress -like "*"} -SearchBase "CN=Sistemas,OU=SISTEMAS,DC=CONTOSO,DC=LOCAL" -properties * |where {$_.Enabled -eq "True"} | where { $_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false } | where { $_.passwordexpired -eq $false }

foreach ($user in $users)
{
$Name = (Get-ADUser $user | foreach { $_.Name})
$emailaddress = $user.emailaddress
$passwordSetDate = (get-aduser $user -properties * | foreach { $_.PasswordLastSet })
$maxPasswordAge = (Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy).MaxPasswordAge
$expireson = $passwordsetdate + $maxPasswordAge
$today = (get-date)
$daystoexpire = (New-TimeSpan -Start $today -End $Expireson).Days
$subject="Correo informativo: Caducidad de Contraseña en $daystoExpire días"
```

Comment: Habría que conocer mas tu estructura; me pregunto qué hay entre la raíz y la primer OU. ¿Has intentado `-SearchBase ""`?

Comment: Que error recibes?